# Refresh Div's content after AJAX form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this Ajax code to submit a PHP form. The code works, however I would like the `<div>` that the content is supposed to change to refresh without the whole page refreshing.

The div's ID is #container.

Here is the AJAX code:

```
$('.accept_friend').submit(function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "../accept_friend.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function( data )
            {
               //here is the code I want to refresh the div(#container)

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('ERROR');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: `$('#container').html(data)` does not work?

Comment: @LucHendriks that justs makes the DIV blank

Comment: Which means there's no `data`

Comment: @LucHendriks thanks, I just had to echo some code in the php file

Comment: might you need `#accept_friend` instead of `.accept_friend` ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to change the DIV's innerHTML property.. with jQuery it is done like so:

```
$('#container').html('... new content goes here...');
```

so in your case add in the success function:

```
$('#container').html(data);
```

or

```
$('#container').html(data.someAttribute);
```

depending on the type and structure of your returned data.